# Period 3 window in chaos

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, bifurcation

Li and Yorke established the fact that period 3 implies chaos, which implies that if we have a period 3 orbit in a system then we have a chaotic system. I have seen that in bifurcation diagrams there exists a period 3 window and that an attractor crisis occurs after the period 3 window due to the unstable orbit created by the saddle node bifurcation colliding with the attractor, but am struggling to understand why the period 3 exists, and how it is produced. If anyone could help me that would be great!

Comment: One small clarification on a very common point of confusion: the period-3 window that you see in bifurcation diagrams of, e.g., the Logistic map actually isn't directly related to the Li-Yorke result, which more specifically says that a _single_ system with a period-3 orbit will have orbits of all orders (as well as chaotic, 'wandering' orbits).

Comment: Ok thanks, still unsure about why it happens in the first place. Could you enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

Since I cannot comment, hence I am posting this in the answers. Kindly have a look at the Sharkovsky ordering to better understand the origins of the statement *period three implies chaos*.
http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Sharkovsky_ordering